# Drupal 7 publishing options unavailable

Tags: drupal, permissions, publish, revision

I have a Magazine Article content-type set up, and a corresponding Magazine Editor role who should have permissions to create and publish articles.

When logged in as administrator, I can see the usual Publishing Options tab at the bottom of the node edit screen for article nodes (ie: */node/56157/edit*), with a checkbox to Publish the node. I can also see the Publish link in the admin sub-menu on a revision page (ie:*/node/56157/revisions/60546/view*). This is all correct.

However: when logged in as a Magazine Editor, I cannot see the Publishing Options tab at the bottom of the node edit screen. There are only three tabs present: "URL path settings", "Revision information" and "Meta tags". Neither do I see the Publish link when viewing an unpublished revision. I want to be able to publish Article nodes when logged in as a Magazine Editor.

Under the role permissions for the Magazine Editor (/admin/people/permissions/11), the following checkboxes are ticked:

Node:

- View published content
- View own unpublished content
- View content revisions
- Magazine Article: Create new content
- Magazine Article: Edit own content
- Magazine Article: Edit any content
- Magazine Article: Delete own content
- Magazine Article: Delete any content

Revisioning:

- View revision status messages
- Edit content revisions
- Publish content revisions (of anyone's content)
- Unpublish current revision (of anyone's content)
- Magazine Article: View revisions of own content
- Magazine Article: View revisions of anyone's content
- Magazine Article: Publish revisions of own content
- Magazine Article: Publish revisions of anyone's content

Googling seems to suggest that I need to set "Administer Nodes" permission under "Node". However, I'm unable to find a permission in the list that looks like "Administer Nodes".

Why are the Publishing options unavailable?

Answer (score 5):

You need to enable the 'Administer Content' permission in the Node section.

Answer (score 2):

You can set permission for publishing contents by using [Publish Content](https://drupal.org/project/publishcontent) module.

> Features
>
> - **Global un/publish any content**
> - **Per "node type" un/publish any [node type] content**
> - **Per user un/publish own [node type] content**
> - (Optionally) adds a "Publish/unpublish" tab, action links or button for one-click un/publishing.
> - Exposes publish/unpublish links to your views, making it easy to streamline workflows for reviewers, editors and publishers.
> - Provides Organic Group permissions allowing group members the specific ability to publish or unpublish content.
> - Provides developer API hooks for programatically allowing or denying publishing access to content for site builders with specific needs

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not convinced that the problem is going to be solved by installing yet another module. I can already set the necessary permissions at the required granularity. I have a permission set that says "give Magazine Editors permission to publish Magazine Article nodes". What I'm unclear on is why that permission isn't giving Magazine Editors the option to publish Magazine Article nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The Revisioning module changes the UI somewhat and is likely hiding that tab set. See the [online documentation](https://drupal.org/node/408968) Specifically, the part about unpublishing content.

> **Unpublish?**
>
> In most revision moderation scenarios content does not
>   often get unpublished. Rather a different revision is made current
>   while the previous revisions is auto-archived.
>
> To remove a piece of content (current and all revisions) from public
>   view without deleting it, you have to unpublish the node. You can do
>   this by unticking the appropriate box on the content editing form.
>   This requires the role to have the "Administer content" permission,
>   which also grants access to a few more options. If you don't want to
>   do this, give the role the more fine-grained "Unpublish current
>   revision" permission instead. Content may then be unpublished from the
>   Revisions tab that sits next to the View tab.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this will fix your problem "Bypass content access control" i also could not publish/unpublish the content.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I understand. Should I be looking for a permission called "Bypass content access control"?

Comment: Yes there is a permission called that way. Please add this permission for the role and check if it works. Afterwards make sure you understand the risks of providing it. There are multiple articles for this. But i dont think you would have problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

We can use [Override node options](https://www.drupal.org/project/override_node_options) module to do this task.
Install module and go to admin->manage users->permissions->roles select a role you want, and click edit permissions.
find override node permissions then select content type you want give permissions to.